# Optimal number of IO thread for different system configuration

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, io, parallel-processing

When we are doing some CPU intensive tasks we do it in parallel to reduce total execution time, we are using parallel execution, and basically optimal number of threads is equal to the Environment.ProcessorCount. It is not always optimal, but in most of cases.

Ok, but what if i have intensive IO bound task with little load on CPU. Basically if CPU is not used intensive in the task it will be faster to use 1 thread, to not get switching overhead. 
But now i realized that many customers (i talk about server software) have raids, striped disk... in some system configurations IO operations could be done in parallel. But how can i find when it is better to use parallel IO and how to find what number of threads should i use? Is there some value like Environment.ProcessorCount for IO, as i know -no. Do you know good way to find optimal number of IO thread for different system configuration?

---

I think that there should be some form of custom Task Scheduler for IO like, which is optimized for IO but i can't find...  IOTaskScheduler - is not optimized for perfomance

Comment: Well, the optimal number of I/O threads is... zero (okay, technically, it's usually one). That's what asynchronous I/O is for - basically, your I/O operations do not consume any CPU, so it's useless to create a new thread for them. Instead, you use asynchronous callbacks, so that you only get a thread when there's actually work to be done on the CPU. `await` and `async` abstract this quite nicely from you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For IO-bound work there is no easy guideline. You don't know what the point of optimal throughput is. It depends on the hardware. For example, SSDs have independent banks of storage. The network has high latency and can benefit from pipelining. Who knows what a remote web-service is like.

Test different values and measure which one is the fastest.

You could even implement a runtime benchmark where you run different degrees of parallelism and pick the fastest. Or you do an adaptive algorithm like the TPL uses. It speculatively increases the number of threads and if throughput increased it keeps the new thread. If it dropped, it retires the thread.

Comment: Thanks, i will try to impliment, i have this idea already but why there is no ready IOTaskScheduler like http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/09/9990424.aspx but optimized for adaptive perfomance for .NET...

Comment: @BransDs I wish there was. Sounds like a fun hobby project for me. I have found that most workloads can be tuned once for a fixed degree of parallelism, though. Does not need to be runtime adaptive.

Answer (score 1):

You can not. THe main problem is that even without a raid controller it hughely depends on the IO load (type). THe moment you add Raid, SAS thigns are out of control. There may be guidelines, but there is no way to measure a best thing. I have a raid array here that sometimes spikes to tens of thousands of outstanding IO requests and between a gb size raid controller cache, a ssd cache and half a dozen SAS discs this gets handled in a second or two at times.

Measure. If you want to look at one item - measure latency.

The moment it takes longer to finish a request, you are waiting in the line. THen optimize for that. Queue size etc. are useless - latency is the only real measurement how busy a IO subsystem it.

Once oyu have that, you can build a feedback loop to adjust the paralellism for optimal size, but then-..... you may get totally SNAFU'd when some other software kicks in (disc scan, anti virus is famous for that).